# how to force .change jquery event without user changing the text in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have few textboxes in my asp.net MVC view which show a popup when user clicks on them. The popup also has a textbox, user enters a value in jquery popup and clicks Ok, the selected value is shown in the textbox which was clicked. I am using textbox.change event on this textbox but it is not fired as the event is fired only If I manually click the textbox.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


            jQuery("#NumberCalledTo").click(function () {
                displayAlertMessage($(this).val());
            });


 $("#dial-prefix").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 470,
        resizeable: true,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                var selectedDialPrefixValue = $("#dialprefixPopup").val();
                var selectedPhoneValue = $("#PhoneNumber").val();

                // remove + and space from dialprefix selected on popup
                selectedDialPrefixwithoutPlus = selectedDialPrefixValue.replace(selectedDialPrefixValue.substring(0, 1), " ");
                selectedDialPrefixwithoutPlus = $.trim(selectedDialPrefixwithoutPlus);

                // number must be 10 or 11 digits long
                if (selectedDialPrefixwithoutPlus == "44" && selectedPhoneValue.substring(0, 1) == "0" && selectedPhoneValue.length < 11) {
                    //displayAlertMessage("Invalid number. Must must have 10 digits.");
                    $("#div-uk-error-message").dialog("open");
                    return;
                }
                else if (selectedDialPrefixwithoutPlus == "44" && selectedPhoneValue.length < 10) {
                    //displayAlertMessage("Invalid number. Must must have 9 digits.");
                    $("#div-uk-error-message").dialog("open");
                    return;
                }

                // remove 0 from phone number
                if (selectedPhoneValue.substring(0, 1) == "0") {
                    selectedPhoneValue = selectedPhoneValue.replace(selectedPhoneValue.substring(0, 1), "");
                }

                if (selectedPhoneValue != '') {
                    var selectedDialPrefix = $("#SelecteddialprefixId").val();
                    var selectedPhone = $("#SelectedPhoneId").val();
                    $("#" + selectedDialPrefix).val(selectedDialPrefixValue);
                    $("#" + selectedPhone).val(selectedPhoneValue);                   
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


});
```

$("#dial-prefix").dialog is opened on textbox click. I can not add any code to OK button function as this popup is being used on different pages and different textboxes.

Please suggest a solution to it

Answer (score 19):

I don't see a change method, so it's hard to decipher the element in question, but if you want to trigger an event, you could just do...

```
$('element').trigger('change');
```

Which will trigger the `change event` and if any `handlers are bound to the event` then they will fire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where do I need to call this event ? in document.ready ? I cant change , $("#dial-prefix").dialog  Ok function as it is generic. Please suggest.

Comment: I tried to change above to    $('#NumberCalledTo').trigger('change');
            jQuery("#NumberCalledTo").change(function () {
                displayAlertMessage($(this).val());
            }); but it didnt work

Comment: @DotnetSparrow is it a typo? In your code above i see a `click` function, but you just sent me a `change` function. Which do you really have? And if the element doesn't exist at the time of the page loading (ajax, or otherwise), then you'll have to bind the event to a static parent element like `$(document).on('change', ' #NumberCalledTo', functoin(){ displayAlertMessage($(this).val()); });`

Comment: oh sorry, its on change, so should i add this static parent element code in document.ready ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Yes. `$(document).ready(function(){//...code });`